# Dúvidas em Windows Forms e C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou tentando aprender C# mas tô com uma baita dificuldade em entender a hierarquia de arquivos e pastas do Solution Explorer do Visual Studio 2013.

Não consigo entender por que existem dois arquivos **.cs**, que se destina um para o *design* do *form* e outro para o código do programa em si.

Emfim, alguém já passou por essa dificuldade em entender a estrutura de arquivos e mais algumas informações importantes na construção do código?

Outra pergunta: é possível criar formulários no C# usando a opção de **Windows Console Application** do VS? Estou me referindo à mesma forma que fazemos no Eclipse quando vamos criar componentes visuais utilizando o código bruto.

Obrigado.

Comment: Eu gostei muito quando vi que o C# e o Basic criam dois arquivos para o Windows Forms. O primeiro com o design do formulário, que ele mesmo escreve pra gente já com o código certinho até com o nome dos eventos, e que não precisamos editar. E o outro com os métodos, que esse a gente mesmo edita. Levei essa ideia para o Eclipse, lá eu crio esses dois arquivos. Do meu ponto de vista, isso ajuda na organização do código e das classes. Já escrever o código no console deve ficar bem difícil para identificar erros depois. Acredito que deva dar um trabalho dobrado.

Answer (score 8):

## Por que existem dois arquivos .cs que se destinam um para o *design* do *form* e outro para o código do programa em si

Um .cs é o fonte do design que você fez na mão. Quando você mandar rodar o programa, esse .cs do design vai rodar e vai colocar os itens na tela com base neste código.

O outro .cs é o código que será rodado com base nos eventos

## Outra pergunta: é possível criar formulários no C# usando a opção de Windows Console Application do VS?

Sim, basta fazer o código abaixo, porém não é o recomendado:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

[STAThread]
static void Main() 
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(new Form());
}
```